# How do I add my mono Program to the startup?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, amazon-ec2

I am very new to Ubuntu. I've a mono application deployed on EC2. Currently I use `mono folder/app.exe` to start the program.
How can I make this run when the system reboots?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:-** In addition to the below answer, I've moved the folder to `/opt`. Otherwise it was throwing library not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using upstart. Example:

/etc/init/app.exe.conf

```
description "My Mono app"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid nobody
setgid nogroup
respawn
console log

exec /path/to/app.exe
```

It will run your app as user nobody, restart it if it crashes and log all output to /var/log/upstart/app.exe.log. To manually start and stop it you'd use "start app.exe" and "stop app.exe".
You can of course name the config file something else, like myapp.conf. See the upstart site for more info: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Tried but I am getting `start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.6" (uid=1000 pid=1198 comm="start omega.in.exe ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")` when I start using `start omega.in.exe`

Comment: you need to be root or use sudo when you start it. Example: sudo start omega.in.exe

Comment: I've noticed a Console.ReadLine not keeping the app running using this method. Is there something going on with stdin and upstart that could cause a newline to go to stdin? I'm a Linux newbie...