# Run Mono Application on Startup with Upstart

Tags: c#, winforms, ubuntu, mono, upstart

I need run a c# Windows Forms application (Mono app) on Ubuntu startup, then I trying use  Upstart. I run this application fine manually, but when I use the Upstart script, as follow:

```
description "Indsys Andon"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

setuid nobody
setgid nogroup
respawn
console log

script
     /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.exe "$@"
end script
```

in Indsys.exe.log the error message appears:

```
A Unhanled Exception : System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was throw
Parameter name: Display
...
```

When I use the script as [How do I add my mono Program to the startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983413/how-do-i-add-my-mono-program-to-the-startup) , so, in Indsys.exe.log the error messages is:

```
run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.exe
```

I don't know rights, but i think that my need is very simple. It's really necessary to use Upstart? I also tried unsuccessfully by rc.local, inserting:

```
 /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.exe
```

Somebody help me, please. Thanks,

Comment: I've been having the same error after number of successful runs of KeePass.exe. Terminal's restart fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends, I solved this demand with another method. Follows:
[Run Mono App on startup in Ubuntu with "startup applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191890/run-mono-app-on-startup-in-ubuntu-with-startup-applications)

Thank you very much for attention!

Answer (score 2):

I think WinForms applications on mono need a valid Xserver running and a valid DISPLAY environment variable. It should be run from a X session or redirect the output to a valid one (it can be on another machine).

To verify, try running your app from a console prepending "DISPLAY='' ".

I get the same error trying to launch keepass (a winforms app) with an empty DISPLAY variable.

```
$ DISPLAY= /usr/bin/mono /usr/share/keepass/KeePass.exe

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable)
Parameter name: Display
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Could not open display (X-Server required. Check you DISPLAY environment variable)
Parameter name: Display
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.SetDisplay (IntPtr display_handle) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at KeePass.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Maybe you could setup a dummy X server, this question may help you: [What dummy X server should I use with openoffice on debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337232/what-dummy-x-server-should-i-use-with-openoffice-on-debian)

Comment: Thank you for answer ilarrain. The error that I get is the same of yours. I try config the Xvfb like [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) , but I have no sucess yet. If you have something about this, will be welcome. Thanks agains.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making a script to call your application, e.g.

```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec /usr/bin/mono PREFIX/lib/APPLICATION/app.exe "$@"
```

Then invoking that script from upstart? It's a long time since I've done this, but I seem to remember doing something like that...

This may also be of help: [Application Deployment](http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines%3aApplication_Deployment)

Comment: Thank you for answer TheNextman. I created a script _IndsysAndon.sh,_ similar to yours, and write a script with `sh /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.sh` in IndsysAndon.exe.conf, but the error remains the same: `A Unhanled Exception : System.TypeInitializationException:...` Thanks again.

Comment: What's the full exception?

Comment: It is like ilarrian answer. Thanks