# Run Mono App on startup in Ubuntu with "startup applications"

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, startup

Relative to same problem of [Run Mono Application on Startup with Upstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163605/run-mono-application-on-startup-with-upstart), here this something that I don't understand:
In "startup applications", (1) I added a new program (Terminal) with the command:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Ok, the terminal opens on Ubuntu startup. (2) Then I changed the command to:

```
gnome-terminal -e nano /home/user/Documents/test.txt
```

Ok, the terminal opens with nano editor. (3) Then I changed the command to:

```
gnome-terminal -e /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.exe
```

And the terminal opens and closes after 1 second, without run de application.
But, when I pastes the command of (3) in a terminal opened in (1), the application runs. Why this happens? Is needed a time to load all dependencies in startup? Thanks

Comment: Good question, but its fitness here is dubious.  You might have better luck at http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the command, ie. `gnome-terminal -e "/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/IndsysAndon/IndsysAndon.exe"`

Comment: Incredible Jester, it works!!!! Thank you very much! If you want, answer the question and I finalizes this post marking your answer. For curiosity, what diference with or whithout quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` expects the command to execute, along with any arguments, as a single string passed via the `-e` option.
If you write

```
gnome-terminal -e foo bar
```

then the command to run will be `foo` and the `bar` will be considered an argument to `gnome-terminal` itself. (Remember that options can appear in any order.)

If you want to pass arguments to the command, you will need to make sure they are passed as a single string to `gnome-terminal`. You can do that by quoting:

```
gnome-terminal -e "foo bar"
```

Unfortunately `gnome-terminal` doesn't use a more user-friendly way, where any subsequent arguments after the command would automatically be considered arguments to the program and not to `gnome-terminal`.